# Foreach implemented on finding array data finds only one data

Tags: php, mysql

Ive used two queried in a function. FIrst query to find an array of data. And second query is to select rows as per checking the array data from the first query. But the overall function return only one row data.

```
function getCartItems($conn)
 {
    $cust_id=$_SESSION['cust_id'];
    $stmtSelect1 = $conn->prepare("SELECT product_id FROM tbl_cart WHERE cust_id=cust_id");
    $stmtSelect1->bindParam('cust_id',$cust_id);
    $stmtSelect1->execute();
    $product_id= $stmtSelect1->fetchAll();

    foreach($product_id as $productid) {
        $stmtfetch = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_item WHERE product_id=:products_id");
        $stmtfetch->bindParam(':products_id',$productid['product_id']);
        $stmtfetch->execute();
         $datas = $stmtfetch->fetchAll();
         print_r($datas);
         exit();
    }
 }
```

Comment: You'll need 1 query (no loop) with the proper `JOIN` on the other table

Comment: Also, `WHERE cust_id=:cust_id`

Comment: @B001ᛦ thanks i did it by performing a join query

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your code has typos (Missing ":" before parameter, product_id/products_id).

This should work:

```
    $cust_id=$_SESSION['cust_id'];
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT tbl_item.* FROM tbl_cart, tbl_item WHERE tbl_cart.cust_id = :cust_id AND tbl_item.product_id = tbl_cart.product_id);
    $stmt->bindParam('cust_id',$cust_id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
    foreach($rows as $row)
    {
        print_r($row);
    }
```